# javascript selected value

Tags: javascript, html

```
            <div id="selected_options">
            <select onchange="test()" id="selected_options">
            <option value="0" selected>-Select-</option>
            <option value="1">Communication</option>
            <option value="2">Hardware</option>
            </select>
    </div>
```

i had written a function for selected value , but when i'm doing alert of selected value it showing up undefined , the function is

```
      function test() {
                    var get_id = document.getElementById('selected_options');
                    var result = get_id.options[get_id.selectedIndex].value;
                    alert(result);
                      }
```

any one please tell me what is the error?

Answer (score 6):

You also have two id's with `selected_options`.  As this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GTGu5/2/) would alert:

```
<div id="selected_options">
    <select onchange="test()" id="selected_opt">
        <option value="0" selected>-Select-</option>
        <option value="1">Communication</option>
        <option value="2">Hardware</option>
    </select>
</div>

function test() {
    var get_id = document.getElementById('selected_opt');
    console.log(get_id);
    var result = get_id.options[get_id.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(result);
}
```

Comment: +1 this is the issue, same thing I came up with http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/qDTdn/ you just beat me to it :P

Comment: @Siva do you have another `id='selected_options'` on your DOM?

Answer (score 3):

The error is here:

```
get_id.options[get_id.selectedIndex].value;
```

It should be

```
get_id.value
```

And it will show up the selected value :)

Answer (score 1):

`get_id[get_id.selectedIndex].value;` "options" not required.

Answer (score 0):

To get the currently selected value you can do:

```
function test() {
    var get_id = document.getElementById('selected_options');
    var result = get_id.value;
    alert(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because your div and select tags have the same id.

Comment: no that is not the problem when i changed also it coming as undefined

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery its much easier:

```
var result = $('#selected_options option:selected').val();
```

and use ids only once

Answer (score 0):

the problem in your code is the same id => 'selected_options' for both div and combobox.

ids are meant for unique element representation in a page.

you can check its live example here:
http://outsourcingnepal.com/projects/kool.htm

code:

```
<script>
function test() {
        var get_id = document.getElementById('selected_options');
    var result = get_id.options[get_id.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(result);
}
</script>
<h1>Outsourcing Nepal</h1>
<a href="http://www.outsourcingnepal.com">Home</a>
<div id="selected_options1">
    <select onchange="test()" id="selected_options">
            <option value="0" selected>-Select-</option>
            <option value="1">Communication</option>
            <option value="2">Hardware</option>
    </select>
</div>
```